# Angular NGRX error while querying the store : TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-effects, ngrx-entity

I have implemented NGRX effects in my angular app and get the error below. I am not sure if I am using the selector correctly in my component to query the store ?

```
core.js:6162 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
  at ngrx-entity.js:21
    at ngrx-store.js:1198
    at memoized (ngrx-store.js:1039)
    at defaultStateFn (ngrx-store.js:1079)
    at ngrx-store.js:1207
    at memoized (ngrx-store.js:1039)
    at ngrx-store.js:1078
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
```

Component

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.initializeForModel();
    //this.users$ = this.store.select(getAllUsers);

    this.store.select(getAllUsers).pipe().subscribe((response:any)=> {
            this.listOfUser = response.users;
            this.userMange = this._createGroup();
        
      });
```

Selector

```
export const userFeatureSelector = createFeatureSelector<UserState>('users');

        export const getAllUsers = createSelector(
          userFeatureSelector,
          selectAll,
          selectIds
        );
```

Service

```
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
          getAllUsers(): Observable<any> {
          return this.http.get("assets/user.json");
          }
        }
```

Reducer

```
  import { EntityState, EntityAdapter, createEntityAdapter } from '@ngrx/entity';
           
           export interface UserState extends EntityState<User> {
      usersLoaded: boolean;
    }

export const adapter: EntityAdapter<User> = createEntityAdapter<User>();

export const initialState  = adapter.getInitialState({
  usersLoaded: false,
  users: [
  
  ],

});

export interface UserState {
  users: User[];
}
        
       export const userReducer = createReducer(
      initialState,
      on(UserActions.loadUsers, (state, { users }) => {
        return adapter.setAll(users, state);
      }),
```

Action

```
export const loadUsers = createAction(
      '[Users List] Load Users via Service',
      props<{ users: User[] }>()
    );
```

Effects

```
loadUsers$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(UserActions.loadUsers),
     mergeMap(() => this.UserService.getAllUsers()
     .pipe(
       map(users => ({ type: UserActions.loadUsers.type, payload: users }))
     // map(users =>  { {console.log(users)} return UserActions.usersLoaded({users})})()
    ))
    )
  );
```

Comment: In your post, I can see you have commented out this.users$ = this.store.select(getAllUsers); . I think its probably the second store.select statement that you would have intended to comment. As it works without the second but not without the first

Answer (score 0):

Don't you miss the return value from selector? And also, effect should return an action which your seems to be not. Don't you get some error also there? If you don't want it, add `{ dispatch: false}` as the second parameter to `createEffect()` function.

```
export const getAllUsers = createSelector(
  userFeatureSelector,
  selectAll,
  selectIds
  (feature, all, ids) => ({ feature, all, ids }) // In VS Code selector is underlined as faulty without this
);
```

EDIT:
Try also dispatching an action from the effect or marking it as an effect without dispatch

```
loadUsers$ = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(UserActions.loadUsers),
    mergeMap(() => this.UserService.getAllUsers()
      .pipe(
        map(users => ({ type: UserActions.loadUsers.type, payload: users }))
      ))
    ),
    //map(mappedUsers => this.store.dispatch(UserActions.saveUser({mappedUsers}))) // - Either dispatch an action to save mapped users
    { dispatch: false} // or add this param so that this effect does not need to dispatch new action
  );
```

I don't work with NgRx entity/data that often so I'm not exactly sure how it works, but generally, **reducer happens before effect**. So if you expect in your `loadUsers` reducer to have data that are supposed to come from BE then you are mistaken. It should be actually an action without the reducer and if the BE call succeeds you can dispatch new action (like `saveUsers) which has the reducer and this one will save your data.

EDIT 2:
I think I understood what were you trying to achieve. You were hoping to modify the payload of the `loadUsers` action with effect, correct? Try this approach:

```
// actions
export const loadUsers = createAction('[Users List] Load Users via Service'); // empty 
export const saveUsers = createAction('[Users Effect] Save Users', props<{ users: User[] }>());

// reducer
on(UserActions.saveUsers, (state, { users }) => {
  return adapter.setAll(users, state);
}),

// effects
loadUsers$ = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(UserActions.loadUsers),
    concatMap(() => this.UserService.getAllUsers()),
    map(users => UserActions.saveUsers({ users }))       
  ));
```

If I understand it correctly, the error comes from NgRx Entity and it happens because your reducer for `loadUsers` has undefined payload. What you tried to to in the effect is not actually updating the payload as the effect happens only after the reducer.

Comment: I am having issue with my Effect too as its not triggering my service. I suspect because it is of the issue you mentioned. What do I need to do fix the effect to return the action

Comment: I have added the extra line that you mentioned but still getting the map undefined error

Comment: Edited the answer. And just a small 'unrelated' comment, if you add `typescript` tag you'll get the code highlight

Comment: Unfortunately tried as you suggested but still struggling to get it to work :)

Comment: Edited again. I think I understand your issue now

Comment: I tried your latest edited solution. It still throws the same error

Comment: Hm, I have no idea what else can be causing this

Answer (score 0):

you need to import the map in Effects from rxjs/operators Like this.

import { map, mergeMap, catchError } from "rxjs/operators";

Comment: I already have those references in the my file

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to reproduce the exact error you were facing but was able to get the store to work.

Simply the structure of a store is like below

1. Dispatch an action

---

Here I changed the action you were initially dispatching to an action without a payload

Now in my actions file I create two actions

```typescript
import { createAction, props } from "@ngrx/store";
import { User } from "../reducers/user.reducer";

export const loadUsers = createAction(
  "[Users List] Load Users"
);

export const loadUsersSuccess = createAction(
  "[Users List] Load Users Success",
  props<{ users: User[] }>()
);
```

And in the component we would have

```typescript
this.store.dispatch(loadUsers());
```

2. Effect receives the action and dispatches another action

---

After we dispatch an action, the effect will receive this action. We will need to call the service and once we receive data dispatch a new action with the payload

```typescript
@Injectable()
export class UserEffects {
  loadUsers$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(UserActions.loadUsers),
      mergeMap(() => this.UserService.getAllUsers()),
      map(users => UserActions.loadUsersSuccess({users}))
    )
  );

  constructor(private actions$: Actions, private UserService: MyService) {}
}
```

3. Reducer receives the action and saves data in store

---

```typescript
export const userReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(UserActions.loadUsers, state => {
    return adapter.setAll(state.users, state);
  }),
  on(UserActions.loadUsersSuccess, (state, { users }) => {
    return adapter.setAll(users, state);
  })
);
```

[See this sample stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hiuj38)

Comment: I have checked your stackblitz. The user array is coming empty. I can also see that you have commented out the use of adapter in the loadusers action. Any reason ?

Comment: @Tom I have updated the solution with a sample selector that selects users as array